# Server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am trying to setup prometheus to monitor nodes, services and endpoints for my kubernetes cluster [1 master, 7 minions ] . For that I have a very basic promethus.yml file :

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
  tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: pod
```

Before starting the Prometheus application , I ran the below 2 commands :

```
export KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=172.9.25.6
export KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=8080
```

I can access the Kubernetes API server using `http://172.9.25.6:8080`

The connect is formed over http and NOT https.

Now when I start the application, I get the below ERROR :

```
level=info ts=2017-12-13T20:39:05.312987614Z caller=kubernetes.go:100 component="target manager" discovery=k8s msg="Using pod service account via in-cluster config"
level=info ts=2017-12-13T20:39:05.313443232Z caller=main.go:371 msg="Server is ready to receive requests."
level=error ts=2017-12-13T20:39:05.316618074Z caller=main.go:211 component=k8s_client_runtime err="github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:205: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://172.9.25.6:8080/api/v1/pods?resourceVersion=0: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client"
```

I also tried to add `scheme: http` to my `prometheus.yml` config but it does not work. How can I configure the client to accept HTTP responses ?

Comment: If you don't specify the apiserver url, it uses the [`InClusterConfig`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/rest/config.go#L317) from k8s. This seems to always want to talk https.  If you do specify it, it [uses it](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/release-2.0/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go#L115) but always fills in a `TLSConfig`. You can try setting `api_server: http://172.9.25.6:8080`, but it may be best to just https your api server (probably a good idea anyway).

Comment: yes its best to use https. do you have ssl confirgured or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying `api_server` inside [kubernetes_sd_configs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/sd_configs.html#kubernetes_sd_configs):

```yaml
scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: pod
    api_server: http://172.9.25.6:8080
```